# How to import scripts for specific browsers Ember-CLi Broccoli

Tags: javascript, html, css, ember.js

Hi I am new to Ember CLI and I have two questions regarding its new Broccoli Build Tool

1. I am importing my styles and javascripts in Brocfile.js using app.import('...'), i read that if we import like these all css and scripts will be compiled to single css and js files. In Some CSS links which i am importing, i used attributes such as ( media='all' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'). For Example Instead of " " I use app.import('vendor/styles/plugins/datatables/bootstrap-datatable.css'); But here i cant use the attributes I used with link tag. I need to know how can I manage to use these attributes to specific css files in brocfile.js.
2. Earlier I used browser specific scripts to work with older versions of IE , in following manner

```js
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src='assets/javascripts/html5shiv.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
        <![endif]-->
```

I need to know is there any way i can import some javascripts to specific browsers , in Ember CLI

Comment: Needing that now as well, but just putting it into the index.html does not seem nice. Because I want to turn off animations in IE. Performance is just too bad.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do the browser-specific imports in `index.html`, don't worry about adding them to your Brocfile.